# How I can begin develop my own oracle database?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

What is the main schema that can be used to develop oracle database for an application. actually, i don't understand at which place i can build my oracle database is there is  public schema that can be used by multip user to build the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBA should create a new user in the database; user is identified by its username and password.

DBA will also have to grant certain privileges to you, such as

- create session
- create table
- create view
- create procedure
- ...

without privileges, you can't do *anything*.

Once DBA provides login credentials to you, you'll be able to establish connection to the database and ... well, do something - create tables, insert data into them, select data etc.

User + all its objects make a *schema*. That should be your *playground* to develop an application.